# Can't install a node module with nopt on ubuntu due to an issue in npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

My Ubuntu is full updated on last version (update, upgrade, dist-upgrade) but when I try to do :

```
mathrobin@mathrobin-pc:~$ sudo npm install -g yo
```

I get this :

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: nopt@'>=2.1.1- <2.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","1.0.10"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:506:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:452:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:427:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:419:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:230:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR!  [Error: No compatible version found: nopt@'>=2.1.1- <2.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","1.0.10"]]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mathrobin
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.9
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.26
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: nopt@'>=2.1.1- <2.2.0-'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.0.8","1.0.9","1.0.10"]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mathrobin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: Your Node is rather old, try [upgrading](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os) (follow the instructions after *Obtaining a recent version...*).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this explanations ! It's working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [yo package.json file](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/blob/master/package.json#L53), it can only be installed if your `node.js` version is `0.8.x` or higher and your `npm` version is `1.2.10` or higher.

Your `node.js 0.8.9` is fine, but your `npm 1.1.26` is too old.

You can upgrade your `npm` version using [official script from npm](https://npmjs.org/install.sh) (Unix only!). Or you may look at [npm Readme.md](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/README.md#super-easy-install) to find alternative options.

Current `npm` version is `1.3.11`.

I also recommend you to install latest stable `node.js` version, which is `0.10.21`. The easiest way to do so is to use some version manager like [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) (may be installed with `npm` with `npm install -g n`).